# Shortest match in Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

This is my regex:

```
/<strong>.*ingredients.*<\/ul>/im
```

Assuming the source code:

```
<strong>Contest closes on Thursday May 10th 2012 at 9pm PST</strong></div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
* I am not affiliated with Blue Marble Brands or Ines Rosales Tortas in any way.&nbsp; I am not sponsored by them and did not receive any compensation to write this post...I just simply think the&nbsp;Tortas&nbsp;are wonderful!<br />
<br />
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-35J5vNrXkqE/T6htXTafrmI/AAAAAAAAA5E/g2mtiuSpSmw/s1600/food+003.JPG" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" height="480" mea="true" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-35J5vNrXkqE/T6htXTafrmI/AAAAAAAAA5E/g2mtiuSpSmw/s640/food+003.JPG" width="640" /></a></div>
<br />
<strong><span style="font-size: large;">Ingredients:</span></strong><br />
<ul>
<li>Ines Rosales Rosemary and Thyme Tortas</li>
<li>Pizza Sauce (ready made in a jar)</li>
<li>Roma Tomatoes</li>
<li>Roasted Red Peppers </li>
<li>Marinated Artichoke Hearts</li>
<li>Olives (I used Pitted Spanish Manzanilla Olives)</li>
<li>Daiya Vegan Mozzarella Cheese</li>
</ul>
<span style="font-size: large;"><strong>Directions:</strong></span><br />
<br />
Spread small amount of pizza sauce over Torta.
```

the Regex is greedy and grabs everything from `<strong>Contest...</ul>` but the shortest match should yield `<strong><span style="font-size: large;">Ingredients...</ul>`

this is my gist: https://gist.github.com/3660370

::EDIT::
Please allow flexibility inbetween strong tag and ingredients, and ingredients and ul.

Comment: Note that with Ruby you can use `%r{..}` to denote your regex literals, so that you don't have to escape forward slashes, e.g. `%r{<strong>.*?ingredients.*?</ul>}im`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - using the nongreedy `?` will not work here with `.*?` because he needs the first `<strong>` to be a late match.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/<strong><span.*ingredients.*<\/ul>/im
```

Please refrain from regex-ing html. Use Nokogiri or a similar library instead.

Comment: +1 for recommending Nokogiri, but -1 for still using the greedy Kleene star instead of the non-greedy `.*?`.

Comment: Nokogiri isn't applicable in this particular case... I use it a lot, but I'm parsing different websites with strong, ingredients, and ul, and random stuff inbetween.. I need to keep it as high level as possible. Sometimes the xml isn't formated well, but the parsing engine should be powerful enough to handle that.

Comment: It was meant as a general guideline. Good you're aware of it. Please accept answer if this gives you the shortest match.

Comment: @DanielSzmulewicz - your regex is applicable to the specific example that OP has given as an assumption. This will still not solve the original problem of a shortest match.

Comment: @Kash. Correct. My apologies, I didn't realize what I was getting into.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
/(?!<strong>.*<strong>.*<\/ul>)<strong>.*?ingredients.*?<\/ul>/im
```

Test it [here](http://rubular.com/r/xlkEsrVXvB)

Basically, the regex is using the negative lookahead to avoid multiple `<strong>` before `<\ul>` like this: `(?!<strong>.*<strong>.*<\/ul>)`

Comment: Very nice solution. I think you meant negative lookbehind though.

Comment: It is still a negative lookahead. Lookbehinds are denoted by `(?<!....)`. Unfortunately, this solution will not work for 3 instances of `<strong>` and `<\ul>`. Need to tweak this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
/<strong>(?:(?!<strong>).)*ingredients.*?<\/ul>/im
```

Replacing the first `.*` with `(?:(?!<strong>).)*` allows it to match anything except another `<strong>` tag before it finds `ingredients`.  After that, the non-greedy `.*?` causes it to stop matching at the first instance of `</ul>` it sees.  (Your sample only contains the one `<UL>` element, but I'm assuming the real data could have more.)

The usual warnings apply: there are many ways this regex can be fooled even in perfectly valid HTML, to say nothing of the dreck we usually see out there.